# Implement Service Layer into Yii Framework

Tags: yii, service-layer

I have started using the Yii framework and am really enjoying the way they do things. Though 1 thing I don't entirely agree with is the all the logic to do with interacting with the database is told to be put into the models. "Skinny controllers, Fat models".

I work in .NET MVC3 at work and though I don't mind putting model specific methods in my models, I believe that abstracting the DB logic into an entirely different service layer makes much more sense to me.

Can anyone throw me ideas on the best way to set this up? I'm thinking something like a class "BaseService" which inherits from Component and each SL object inheriting from that. Would this be a good way to do it?

Comment: Do you have some classes schema of that solution? Or some draft/exampe? Once i was working with such system with service, model and some other class, and I felt like clugged with those classes:) Because i had to remember that for some purpose i have to use this, for other that... And with many models and services i was quite a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new folder protected/serviceLayer

import this folder in your config/main.php

```
'import' => array('application.serviceLayer.*')
```

create a component in your protected/serviceLayer- folder

call it wherever you want

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing :-)